# Looking for an efficient way to index 2D tensor by another 2D tensor in pytorch

Tags: indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor, say

```
A = tensor([
            [0, 0],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [0, 4],
            [0, 5],
            [0, 6],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [1, 4],
            [1, 5],
            [1, 6]
       ])
```

and the other tensor

```
b = tensor([[0, 2], [1, 2]])
```

I would like to find an efficient way to index into A by b such that the result is

```
result = tensor([[0, 3], [1, 4]])
```

That is, match A’s first column of last dim (i.e. [0,…,1…]) with b’s first column of the last dim (i.e. [0,1]) by their values and then use b’s second column (i.e. [2, 2]) to index A’s second column.

Thanks

Comment: Does your first column in `A` always contain sequential values? Are the first column values in `A` always contiguous? It is not clear what are the edges cases of your problem

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I convert it into one dimensional problem with torch.nonzero and offset by mask sum, and work out a solution.
Instead of the original A, get a flatten version, like
````
A = tensor([[ 0],
   [ 2],
   [ 3],
   [ 4],
   [ 5],
   [ 7],
   [ 8],
   [11],
   [12]])
````
and also calculate the offsets along batch,
````
offset = tensor([[0],
     [5],
     [4]])
````
Similarly, get b
````
b = tensor([2, 2])
````
and
````
offset_b = b+offset.reshape(-1)[:-1]
````
Then 
````
indices=A.reshape(-1)[offset_b]
````

Comment: Good, you can write an answer below and accept it in order to close this thread!

Answer (score 0):

Work out a solution by converting it to one dimensional problem with torch.nonzero and offset by mask sum.

Instead of the original A, get a flatten version, like

```
A = tensor([[ 0], [ 2], [ 3], [ 4], [ 5], [ 7], [ 8], [11], [12]])
```

and also calculate the offsets along batch,

```
offset = tensor([[0], [5], [4]])
```

Similarly, get b

```
b = tensor([2, 2])
```

and

```
offset_b = b+offset.reshape(-1)[:-1]
```

Then

```
indices=A.reshape(-1)[offset_b]
```